# Is there a way to use Quaternion.FromToRotation to favor using one axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I've been struggling with this problem for too many hours and it's time for me to ask for your help.

**Situation**

I have a moving character I walk around with and align with the surface it walks on. I do this by raycasting down to the next surface it's going to be on and getting the rotation needed to align to the surface with

```
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, foundSurface.normal) * transform.rotation;
```

The character is a transform called Modelholder that smoothly rotates to the new rotations with

```
modelHolder.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(modelHolder.rotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime * modelRotationSmoothing);
```

Inside of the modelHolder is the model. I change model.localRotation.y based on mouse jaw movement.

The camera is just a transform that follows the modelholder and has a child transform called Rotator that rotates based on mouse movement too (this time jaw and pitch). The camera is a child of this Rotator transform.

With this, I can walk up walks and ceiling while properly aligning to everything, pretty neat.

**Problem**

I made a grappling hook which moves the character to grappled surfaces. The realignment at the end of the flight is done in the same way as the walking alignment. This all works fine, except for when you grapple from ground to ceiling (or vice versa). The model seems to do a "barrel roll" to realign to the new surface when I look east or west, but will do a back- or frontflip when looking north or south.

ModelHolder movement:
https://streamable.com/qf94k

Model movement:
https://streamable.com/4xkl4

The barrel roll is fine, but I want to somehow find a way to rotate so that the player won't be looking in the opposite direction after landing (or jumping from the ceiling while looking north or south, because then realignment to gravity will cause the flip as well) because the flip is terrible disorienting.

Things I've tried:

- I tried having no separation in modelHolder and model. This doesn't solve the problem and only gives me more problems with having a smooth but responsive camera.
- I tried saving the lookdirection before realignment and rotation to the old lookdirection while realigning.
  This just does a super weird flip and turn thing which is even more disorienting.
- I tried trying to detect differences in comparisons between old and new rotations to see if I can somehow "detect" when it wants to do a flip and when it wants to do a barrel roll so I can counter this. I found only confusion and frustration.

Comment: I love, love, love the fact that you took a video of your problem and made your model look like the unity axes. I really wish more people would do that when they ask about rotations.

Comment: What object is this script attached to? Why do you use `transform.up` instead of `modelHolder.up`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate a `newRotation` that maintains the forward direction as much as possible while having the local up be the normal of the surface.

`FromToRotation` only guarantees one axis of alignment in the way that you're using it. Instead, you can use cross products and `Quaternion.LookRotation` to do the calculation you need.

```
Vector3 newPlayerRight = Vector3.Cross(foundSurface.normal, modelHolder.forward);
Vector3 newPlayerForward = Vector3.Cross(newPlayerRight, foundSurface.normal);

Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newPlayerForward, foundSurface.normal);
```

Then, you can proceed as before:

```
modelHolder.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(modelHolder.rotation, newRotation, 
        Time.deltaTime * modelRotationSmoothing);
```

Although I don't endorse using Slerp/Lerp methods with a `t`that isn't guaranteed to ever reach or exceed 1. I would instead recommend using `Quaternion.RotateTowards`:

```
float modelRotationSpeed = 180f;
modelHolder.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(modelHolder.rotation, newRotation, 
        Time.deltaTime * modelRotationSpeed);
```

In order to maintain the forward angle relative to the edge just traversed, you can try a different method:

```
Quaternion newRotation;

// ..

Vector3 previousSurfaceNormal = modelHolder.up;
Vector3 previousForward = modelHolder.forward;
bool flyingOrFallingToNewSurface;

if (flyingOrFallingToNewSurface)
{
    Vector3 newPlayerRight = Vector3.Cross(foundSurface.normal, modelHolder.forward);
    Vector3 newPlayerForward = Vector3.Cross(newPlayerRight, foundSurface.normal);

    newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newPlayerForward, foundSurface.normal);
} else
{
    // This direction lies in both surfaces. 
    Vector3 edgeTraversed = Vector3.Cross(previousSurfaceNormal, foundSurface.normal);

    // Find the angle from edgeTraversed to previousForward
    float ang = Vector3.SignedAngle(edgeTraversed, previousForward, previousSurfaceNormal);

    // Find newForward in new plane that's the same angle
    Vector3 newPlayerForward = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang,foundSurface.normal) * edgeTraversed;

    newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newPlayerForward, foundSurface.normal);
}

// ...

float modelRotationSpeed = 180f;
modelHolder.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(modelHolder.rotation, newRotation, 
        Time.deltaTime * modelRotationSpeed);
```

Comment: Thanks! These cross products and lookrotation are definitely useful! 
I unfortunately couldn't get it to work full, though. I tried making the modelholder rotate and keep it's forward like you showed, but because the modelHolder doesn't rotate with the camera (check videos), this doesn't fully work. And I can't rotate the modelHolder based on the model's forward, because that will cause the modelHolder to reallign with the local y rotation of the model.

Comment: @RobinHerben thanks for the reply. I'll take another crack at this later today.

Comment: @RobinHerben I asked a clarification on the question but in the meantime, what happens if you do `Vector3 newPlayerRight = Vector3.Cross(foundSurface.normal, modelHolder.forward);` instead?

Comment: That wouldn't work either. But! I got it to work by not having a separated Model and ModelHolder and by using your cross products and lookrotation method! Marked your answer as accepted, thank you!

Comment: I stumbled upon a new problem: https://streamable.com/ekrov
When alligning to a new surface with an angle, you will rotate away from where you were looking at a little bit. Do you know how to achieve it so that you can walk back and forth on a surface like this, but still keep the look direction? I really thought about it but I think I broke my brain over this :D

Comment: @RobinHerben I would ask a new question and include information about what you're working with right now (I have no idea how your camera is set up, for starters) but something along the lines of this might help: `Vector3 previousCameraForward;` `Quaternion cameraPivotGoal = Quaternion.LookRotation(previousCameraForward, foundSurface.normal);` `cameraHolder.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(cameraPivot.rotation, cameraPivotGoal, Time.deltaTime * cameraRotationSpeed);` `/*update camera controller internal values*/` (assuming your camera has a pivot parent like here)

Comment: the camera is not related to the problem I have; the same thing happens without the camera. With "look direction" I basically meant the forward direction of the transform relative to the world.

Comment: @RobinHerbern I see, that clears things up. Well, that only makes sense when you're moving along the ground, which isn't what the question was originally about. In the case of "walking" like that, the axis of rotation is fixed and you're concerned with keeping the forward the same relative to the axis of rotation. In the case of flying/falling, you're concerned with the absolute forward, and the axis of rotation is whatever it needs to be to keep it as close as possible. I added a part to my answer to hopefully address that.  If that doesn't help, please consider asking a separate question.

Comment: You're a god amongst men! I will try this all tomorrow, if it doesn't work I will ask a separate question. I really appreciate all your help, thank you!